# Using data class in micronaut properties

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I'm writing configuration properties and would like to use data class to hold the data.

Problem is, data classes have a primary constructor and are immutable, and micronaut tries to inject the values as beans.

Example:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("gerencianet")
data class GerenciaNetConfiguration(

    val clientId: String,

    val clientSecret: String,

    val apiUrl: String,

    val notificationUrl: String,

    val datePattern: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

)
```

Error: `Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [java.lang.String] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements`

Is there support for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to do something like this:

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.ConfigurationBuilder
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.ConfigurationProperties

@ConfigurationProperties("my.engine")
internal class EngineConfig {
    @ConfigurationBuilder(prefixes = ["with"])
    val builder = EngineImpl.builder()

    @ConfigurationBuilder(prefixes = ["with"], configurationPrefix = "crank-shaft") / <3>
    val crankShaft = CrankShaft.builder()

    @set:ConfigurationBuilder(prefixes = ["with"], configurationPrefix = "spark-plug") 
    var sparkPlug = SparkPlug.builder()
}
```

That is from our test suite at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/1c3e2c3280da200c96e629a4edb9df87875ef2ff/test-suite-kotlin/src/test/kotlin/io/micronaut/docs/config/builder/EngineConfig.kt.

You can also inject the values as constructor parameters using `@Value`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Inject using constructor parameters looks like what I want. For now a follow the option of using a normal class with var and a secondary constructor:

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the values as constructor parameters using `@Parameter`. It [avoids common mistakes with `@Value`](https://blog.nareshak.com/micronaut-the-common-mistake-with-the-use-of-value/).

For example, if your `application.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
group:
  first-value: asdf
  second-value: ghjk
```

Then a Kotlin class might look like:

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Property
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class MyClass(@Property(name = "group.first-value") val firstValue: String) {
    fun doIt(): String {
        return firstValue
    }
}
```

Or, similarly, a method:

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Property
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Factory
class MyFactory {
    @Singleton
    fun getSomeValue(@Property(name = "group.first-value") firstValue: String): SomeClass {
        return SomeClass.newBuilder()
            .setTheValue(firstValue)
            .build()
    }
}
```